# jQuery add parameters to $(document).on('click','#id',function(){})

Tags: jquery, listener

I am using this part of code

```
   $(document).on('click','.class',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();.....
   })
```

I use it like this because I need listeners on nonexisting elements, that are created dynamically.
But I want to use it like this:

```
function foo(e){
   e.preventDefault();....
}

$(document).on('click','.class',foo(this));
```

Any ideas on how to properly write code like this?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that you just want to define the function separately, you can certainly do that.  Just don't *invoke* the function when setting the click handler.  Simply pass a reference to it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', foo);
```

The framework sends the event object to the handler function by default, so `e` will still be passed as with any other click handler.

Comment: I tought that I have to pass parameter in listener. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
function prevent(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Correct');
}

$(document).on('click','.class', prevent);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/2sdja6zy/4/